# Cant login into pgAdmin 4 with docker

Tags: docker, pgadmin

I feel like its highly stupid question, but I just cant log into my pgAdmin.
My compose.yml file is

```
services:
  back:
    container_name: blog-django
    build: ./blog-master
    command:  gunicorn blog.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    expose:
    - 8000
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - blog-django:/usr/src/app/
      - blog-static:/usr/src/app/static
      - blog-media:/usr/src/app/media

    env_file: ./.env
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
  nginx:
    container_name: blog-nginx
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - "1337:80"
    volumes:
      - blog-static:/usr/src/app/static
      - blog-media:/usr/src/app/media

    links:
      - back
    depends_on:
      - back 

  db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres:14
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: docker
      POSTGRES_USER: docker
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: docker
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U docker"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
    depends_on: 
      - db
    links: 
      - db 

  mailhog:
    container_name: mailhog
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    #logging:
    #  driver: 'none'  # disable saving logs
    expose:
      - 1025
    ports:
      - 1025:1025 # smtp server
      - 8025:8025 # web ui


volumes:
  blog-django:
  blog-static:
  blog-media:
  pgdata:
  pgadmin-data:
```

and my .env file is

```
DEBUG=1
SECRET_KEY='a key'
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1 [::1]
SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
SQL_DATABASE=docker
SQL_USER=docker
SQL_PASSWORD=docker
SQL_HOST=db
SQL_PORT=5432
DATABASE=postgres
```

but with any username/email and password it keeps saying "wrong email/password". although if I login with "admin@admin.com" error is **"Incorrect username or password"** and with username it says **"email/username is not valid"**
I tried using admin@mailhog.local email so I can do password recovery, but again, **"Incorrect username or password"**

Comment: Were you able to resolve?  If so, what was it?

Comment: I tried everything on StackOverflow but it didn't solve my issue. Then I tried to remove the volume directory manually, and it worked.